# $dirty is always false if I display form using ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two forms which I want to display conditionally, so I use ng-show for that. Now I'm using $dirty for validation purpose but in my case $dirty is always equal to false even if I enter some value in my input field.

Any Idea ?

Comment: can you share some `code`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I had just forgotten the ng-model in the input fields so there actually nothing was dirty.